# Can anyone share the complete meaning of Lalitha Sahasranama? I have come across word to word translations, but need a proper explanation

Tags: stotra, lalita, lalita-sahasranama

Can anyone share the complete meaning of Sri Lalitha Sahasranama? I have come across word to word translations, but need a proper explanation.

Comment: **Proper explanation** is a tricky phrase. An explanation given by one translator, may not be appealing to everyone.  Then your question will become opinion based, and is liable to be closed.

Comment: You can buy Sowbhagya Bhaskara if possible. I think u need to read commentary and u'll get that in the book.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few commentaries available for Sri Lalitha Sahasranama, and **Bhaskararaya's commentary has been published in English, translated by Sri Anantakrishna Sastri**. This is a full commentary and not just word by word meaning.This is what I recommend.

You can order it online if you like. Search for "Bhaskararaya" and "Lalitha Sahasranama" and "Anantakrishna Sastry" to find a printed copy of the book. Originally published by Adyar libraries.

[Here is an archives resource - click on this text. Note that this is his original commentary in Sanskrit](https://archive.org/details/Sri_lalita_sahasra_nama_with_saubhagyabhaskara_and_bhaskaravilasaKavyam/mode/2up)

[Here is the one published by Sri Ramakrishna Matam](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8178230992)

[Here is a more modern work by another author available on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1456417630)

Answer (score 0):

This website has meanings in English.  Does that  help?

https://www.hinduwebsite.com/prayers/sri-lalitha-sahasranama-sthothram.asp